# add css or class to product by sku

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to custom a design for some catalog products who have a specific attribute.

i added an attribute to edit tab products in admin, i get a collection by the attribute filter. now i want when the product has the attribute, i apply some design or add some class on it.

My collection:

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('promo', 1)
                                    ->setPageSize(10);                              
?>

<?php foreach($collection as $col): ?>
<?php echo $col->getSku(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I found a solution as simple width a help of Piyush , i add a myCustomclass in class product if i get the attribute

The default div

```
<div class="row item border-items-list">
//Product
</div>
```

the add class

```
<div class="row item border-items-list <?php if ($col->getSdPromotionSogge()){echo 'promo-design';}?> ">
//Product
</div>
```

Comment: hello you need whole layout need diffrent or just product section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class like this-

```
<?php if($col->getYourAttribute()) 
 {
     $styleClass = 'promo-design';
 }
 // if you want another class if attribute not available then add this else condition

 else
 {
     $styleClass = 'other_class'; 
 }
?>


<div class="row item border-items-list <?php echo $styleClass ?>" > <?php echo $col->getSku(); ?> // the product </div>
```

Comment: add html where you want to add class

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Tell me piyush, in catalog/product/list i have ($_productCollection as $_product),  instead to do my new collection with the attribute ->addAttributeToFilter('promo', 1) i have do $_product->getPromo() but it doesnt work

Comment: try `$_product['promo']` instead of `$_product->getPromo()`

Comment: its not working